# C - How can you create a global array, who's size is the integer result of a function?

Tags: c, linux, pthreads, global-variables, threadpool

Basically I want to create a thread pool, so I've made an array to store the fixed number of threads.

```
#define num_of_threads (sysconf(_SC_NPROCESSORS_ONLN)*2)

static pthread_t threadpool[num_of_threads];
```

The variable 'threadpool' is a global (declared outside of all functions), and I need it to be, as multiple different functions use it.

Rather than just giving a fixed number of threads like 4 or 8, I thought I'd be clever and found out the number of cores any Linux system has, using:

```
sysconf(_SC_NPROCESSORS_ONLN)
```

and then use that to determine the number of threads to create.

Problem is you can't have a variably modified variable at a file scope, is there any way to overcome this? Or is what I'm trying to do unnecessary to begin with?

Thanks.

Comment: Use pointers and dynamic allocation early?

Comment: You should note that most threadpools are designed as multiple work threads hanging off a producer-consumer queue and, as such, it is not required to store any pthread_t's at all.  Such designs make it easy to configure, add or remove threads from the pool at startup or during the app run at any time.  You could add 1000 threads during the run without any problem with fixed-size array suckage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A variable at file scope has *static storage duration*, which means it exists during the whole run time of the program. Therefore, its size must be fixed. If you first have to execute something to determine the size, the object can't exist already.

But nothing prevents you from having a global *pointer* initialized to `0`. In some initialization code, you can allocate your array with `malloc()` and assign it to the pointer like this:

```
static pthread_t *threadpool;
static size_t num_of_threads;

static void initThreadpool(void)
{
    num_of_threads = sysconf(_SC_NPROCESSORS_ONLN) * 2;
    threadpool = malloc(num_of_threads * sizeof *threadpool);
    if (!threadpool) exit(1);
}
```

Take care that you design this in a way so only one thread actually tries to create this array.